# TypeError when using regex to change column names in polars

Tags: python-polars

I have a df:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A": [0],
    "B": [1],
    '{"C_C", "1"}': [2],
    '{"D_D", "6"}': [3],
})
```

I want to change the column names so that if they have quotation marks they are joined with an underscore and `_count` is added at end, so `{"C_C", "1"}` becomes `C_C_1_count`. I have tried:

```
def flatten_pivot_polars(d:pl.DataFrame, col_str: str)->pl.DataFrame:

  import re

  d=d.select(
        pl.exclude(["Step", "RunId"]).name.map(lambda col_name: 
           '_'.join([re.findall('"([^"]*)"',col_name), col_str]))
        )
  return d

flatten_pivot_polars(df, 'count')
```

but this gives:

```
ComputeError: Python function in 'name.map' produced an error: 
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found.
```

I am guessing it is because I am not excluding the non quoted columns properly but don't know what else to do.

Comment: Are you getting these odd column names from calling `.pivot()`? It's possible there is a nicer way to go from pre-pivot -> expected result instead of post-processing the result. Perhaps it would make for a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns all non-overlapping matches, as a list of strings. You want to append `col_str` to this list. For this, you can use the following.

```
re.findall('"([^"]*)"',col_name) + [col_str]
```

Instead of

```
[re.findall('"([^"]*)"',col_name), col_str]
```

which would end up with a nested list `[[matches], col_str]`.

Comment: Just to add to this, I think you also need a conditional for the approach to work as expected: `.join() if '"' in col_name else col_name` otherwise it will produce the string `count` for any non-matching column names.

Comment: @jqurious True - this is under the assumption that the `pl.exclude` in the question sorts out any non-matching column names.